# File downloaded through php corrupts/increases in size?

Tags: php, download, zip

I have this code:

```
    $file = $tempDir . "/download.zip";
    // there's some omitted code here that creates the file that's to be downloaded

    if(file_exists($file) && is_readable($file)) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/zip');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($file);
    }else{
        return "Error: Failed to retrieve file.";
    }
```

The code that generates the file works fine, and after hitting the button for downloading, I see it appear in its appropriate place, at 1 KB. The file is also usable. When I download, it even says it's "973 bytes". When the file actually downloads though, it's suddenly 9.1 KB, and completely corrupted. Why?

Comment: Have you downloaded the file direct without doing it through PHP? Do you get the same results?

Comment: I don't think I will. I think that the problem lies in the output buffer being written to by other things in this php file.

Comment: I don't know why it is but when I upload files to the web and download them it sometimes changes, even directly through a FTP connection.

Answer (score 0):

does the code omitted run a background program? If you run a command line program (exec etc) to create the zip file you may be serving an incomplete file.

upload a zip file that you know works, remove the code to create a zip and see if that is served correctly. if it isn't let me know and i'll take a look.
is this windows or linux?

also the size of the file may vary slightly. windows adds meta data, created,added,modified etc that can effect the file size